# AppDelegate update with Firebase

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to add the following code to my main `AppDelegate`, I have 2 files called `AppDelegate`, `AppDelegate.m`, `AppDelegate.h`, which one do I need to edit?

Neither file has **@import** they both have **#import**

```
@import UIKit;
@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [FIRApp configure];
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: You can add the `[FIRApp configure];` in the `AppDelegate.m` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@import** is available since `iOS` 7 and is an improvement on **#import** (see for example [this blogpost](http://www.davitsiradeghyan.com/post/130287171375/import-vs-import-in-objective-c) for more info). You should be able to use `@import Firebase;`, but otherwise it'd be `#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>`